# What's the preferred way to include QML sources in your application build?

Tags: build, qt4, qmake, qml

I am building an application with mixed UI technologies (mostly C++ with some QML components included).

Suppose I have a QML item which I want to show inside a `QDeclarativeView` using syntax like this:

```
view = new QDeclarativeView(QUrl::fromLocalFile("foobar.qml"));
```

I have added foobar.qml to my project in Qt Creator which automatically adds this line to the .pro file:

```
OTHER_FILES += \
    foobar.qml
```

Now, you would expect including the file into the project to imply that it should be copied to the build folder, but it doesn't, and I get an error about missing foobar.qml in the build folder when I run the application. I'd hate to add custom build steps just to copy QML sources around, so is there some "de facto" way of doing this?

Comment: I have the same question and want to load qml from local file instead of qrc but *it wasn't copied to the build folder*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One obvious solution would be to include the QML source through Qt's [resource system](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/resources.html). This is hinted at on the doc page about [deploying QML based applications](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmlruntime.html#deploying-qml-based-applications).

EDIT: Here is the [complete solution](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtbinding.html#managing-resource-files-with-the-qt-resource-system). I should learn to RTFM.

Comment: This is what I do in my application. Basically something like `view = new QDeclarativeView(QUrl("qrc:/qml/scene.qml"));`

Comment: Yep, resources would be the right way to go. Unless the application lives in a protected environment - or you don't care, in which case you can ship side by side. In Mac Bundles you would typically put them inside the bundle resources folder

Comment: What if I want to use qml file instead of qrc? I want the qml file be copied to the build directory.

Answer (score 3):

Do you use shadow builds? If so the application is build in a directory parallel to the source code. For testing you can change the working directory in Qt Creator (Projects in the left bar, then Execution of your build target). 
Using resources seems fool-proof, but it requires a rebuild every time any of the resources are changed.